# Stopping input while a key is being pressed

Tags: c#, key

How would i code an if statement like this so that null is checking if no key is pressed.
(this wont work as the key will never equal null)

```
if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == null)
{
    pressingSpace = false;
}
```

Not sure things to try as I have only just started working on C#

Comment: Please expand on what you're trying to do. Stopping input while a key is pressed sounds like a contradiction to me.